# Apex Triggers Copy Primary Contact Role into lookup field in the opportunity page

Tags: apex, trigger, contact, opportunitycontactrole

I copy this formula and it works great when the lookup field is null but if I want to change the Primary contact Role the lookup field does not change (it keeps the first contact Role assigned)
Can you please help me to change this code so it works not only when is null but also when there is an existing contact role in the look up field? Thanks.

```
trigger CopyPrimaryContact on Opportunity (before update) {

// THIS TRIGGER WILL OVERWRITE ANY CONTACT DEFINED IN THE CUSTOM FIELD OPPORTUNITY_CONTACT__C ON THE OPPORTUNITY OBJECT.
// SET THIS FIELD TO READ ONLY OR CHANGE THE FUNCTIONALITY BELOW TO AVIOD DATA BEEING OVERWRITTEN BY MISTAKE...


   List<OpportunityContactRole> contactRoleArray = [select ContactID, isPrimary from OpportunityContactRole where Role != 'Dealer Sales Rep' and OpportunityId IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet() ORDER BY isPrimary DESC, createdDate];

   for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {

       // CREATE ARRAY OF ALL CONTACT ROLES ON THIS OPPORTUNITY. THE REASON WHY WE DONT PICK THE PRIMARY CONTACT ROLE ONLY 
       // IS BECAUSE THE PRIMARY FLAG IS NOT SET WHEN LEADS ARE CONVERTED TO OPPORTUNITIES. ONLY WHEN CREATING OPPORTUNITIES
       // MANUALLY FROM THE CONTACT OBJECT THE IS PRIMARY CHECKBOX IS CHECKED...

       if (o.Primary_Contact__c == null && contactRoleArray.size() > 0) {

           // IF PRIMARY IS DEFINED THEN THIS WILL BE THE FIRST OBJECT. IF NOT THE FIRST ADDED CONTACT ROLE WILL BE ADDED...
           o.Primary_Contact__c = contactRoleArray[0].ContactID;

       }
   }
 }
```

Comment: It appears that you are aware of the condition that the code is checking for before it updates the primary contact value... have you attempted any solution, such as removing `o.Primary_Contact__c == null &&` from the conditions? Do you receive an error preventing it from doing what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot to cover here.

First of all, this trigger is going to cause incorrect data updates because it's iterating through Opportunities in Trigger.new but it's always referencing contactRoleArray[0] which means that every Opportunity updated at the same time will be related to the same OpportunityContactRole, which is clearly incorrect because an OpportunityContactRole can only belong to a single Opportunity. The correct way to do this would be to query for OpportunityContactRole "WHERE isPrimary = true" instead of "ORDER BY isPrimary" and then loop through the OpportunityContactRole results, adding them to a Map where the key is the OpportunityId and the value is the OpportunityContactRole. Then you would get the correct OpportunityContactRole from the map using the Opportunity.Id when looping through Opportunities in Trigger.New.

However, none of that really matters because this trigger won't fire when you change the primary contact role because the trigger is on the Opportunity object, not the OpportunityContactRole. I suppose eventually the Opportunity will likely get updated at some point, and then it would pick up the new OpportunityContactRole, but not when you want it to.

Unfortunately, you cannot trigger on the OpportunityContactRole. I don't know if Salesforce has ever explained why, because it feels like an arbitrary limitation, but it's been that way since I've been developing for Salesforce.

What I recommend is that you write a batch job to do this instead of relying on a Trigger. It does mean that the update won't happen in real time, but it's probably the best solution.